# How exactly does Halmos define an ordered pair?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Halmos writes in "Naive Set Theory":

> Given the set ${X}$, consider the collection $W$ of all well-ordered subsets of $X$. Explicitly: an elememt of $W$ is a subset $A$ of $X$ together with a well ordering of $A$. We partially order $W$ by continuation.

Then he goes on and writes:

> The collection $W$ is not empty, because, for instance $\emptyset\, 
>  \epsilon \,W$. If $X \neq \emptyset$, less annoying elements of $W$ can be exhibited; one such is {($x, x$)}, for any particular element $x$ of $X$.

My problem is that Halmos defined earlier in section 6 about Ordered Pairs that an ordered pair is defined as follows:
$(a, b) = \{\, \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.
And if $a=b$ then we have
$(x,x)= \{\{x\}\}$.
My problem/question is that if $W$ contains subsets of $X$ and if $x$ is an element of $X$, then why is
{($x, x$)} in $W$? By the definition of an ordered pair that Halmos gave we can only conclude that $(x,x)\, \epsilon \,W$.

Comment: You just need to insert a few words into Halmos's text to address this nitpick. Halmos means something like: "*... one such is given by the well-ordering $\{(x, x)\}$ of the singleton set $\{x\}$ for any particular element $x$ of $X$*". Did this really cause you any great difficulty in your understanding of the argument?

Comment: @Rob Arthan I simply did not know what exactly W consisted of. He mentions subsets but a gave an explanation of togethernes in earlier chapters that implies that elements of W are ordered pairs but then again the only plausible explanation so far is the one given by GEdgar.

Comment: On further reflection, it would be better if Halmos had not written "Explicitly, an element of $W$ is  a well-ordering together with [something else]". In the proof he takes unions of chains in $W$, so it makes more sense for the elements of $W$ to be the well-orderings without any other encumbrances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a "well-ordered set" means just a well-ordering relation.

That is, when we would normally write $(E,R)$ where $E$ is the set and $R$ is the order relation on $E$, in fact it is enough to write only $R$ (since we can recover $E$ from $R$).  So, for example, $R=\{(x,x)\}$ is the unique well order relation on the set $\{x\}$, so (in this understanding) $R$ is a well-ordered set.

Comment: This is possible. I just reread a paragraph in his section about orders(p.55 for everyone interested) where mentions that a partially ordered set is a set together with a partial order in it. He explains this togethernes as the ordered pair of the set and the order-relation as you did in your post. Then he admits that it would suffice when talking about orders to only mean the relation as it implies knowledge about the domain and thus about the set on which the order is defined.

Comment: But at the end he clarifies that it is the costumary way to mean the former one(the ordered pair  consisting of set and and relation). It seems like he broke with the costum here, otherwise i dont know how to interpret all the definitions and statememts without a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I think Halmos contradicts himself here.

It is a fact that given a well-ordering of a set, you can retrieve the set from the well-ordering. So it would be natural to define $W$ as the set of well-orderings on subsets of $X$. With this understanding, $\{(x,x)\}$ is a well-ordering (in fact the only well-ordering) of the set $A=\{x\}$, so it would indeed be an element of $W$ (and is equal to $\{\{\{x\}\}\}$, as you say).

But he *explicitly* defines an element of $W$ as a subset $A\subset  X$ *together with* a well-ordering of $A$. Exactly what "together with" means here is not perfectly clear, but a natural interpretation would be the ordered pair consisting of $A$ and a well-ordering of $A$. And in this case $\{(x,x)\}$ is not an element of $W$; rather you would need $(\{x\},\{(x,x)\})$.

Comment: i think "together with" means that if A is an element of W then A is a subset of X that can be well-ordered. So there exists an order(a subset of the Cartesian Product of X) where the domain is A and the order itself, essentially a relation, is such that it is an partial order and satisfies the well-ordering property. This means that every subset of A has a smallest element with respect to the defined order.

Comment: I dont know if a set can only be well-ordered in only one way but i dont think so, therefore it does not matter wether A can be well-ordered in several ways because it will only appear in W once. Then we would have that an element of W would have the form A={a,b,...} where  a,b,..etc. are elements of X. We then only know that the set A is a subset of X and that it can be well-ordered in at least one way. But this speaks against the statement of Halmos that {(x, x)} is in W.

Comment: I see no contradiction in Halmos's text, just some slightly loose writing.

Comment: @EinsteinsCorrespondecePrincipe: any set with two or more elements admits more than one well-ordering. And Halmos _explicitly_ includes the well-ordering when he says "together with". So your interpretation can't be right -- for any given subset of $A$, there are in general many elements of $W$, each with a different well-ordering of $A$.

Comment: @TonyK Thx for clarification.